# Applying function on two columns, refers to previous row - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I've got data frame that include x and y variables, and the indexes are: ID, date and time. 
I want to create new variable that will be created by applying some defined function.

For example, the function could be:

```
def some_function(x1, x2 , y1, y2):
    z = x1*x2 + y1*y2
    return z
```

- The real function is more complex.

Note: The function should be applied on each ID separately.

Data illustration:

```
ID  date        time    x   y
1   08/27/2019  18:00   1   2
                19:00   3   4
                20:00   ..  ..
                21:00   ..  ..
2   08/28/2019  18:00   ..  ..
                19:00   ..  ..
                19:31   ..  ..
                19:32   ..  ..
                19:34   ..  ..
```

So for example, the first row in the new variable should be 0, since there is no previous row, and the second row should be 3*1 + 4*2 = 11.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with shift:

```
df_shifted= df[['x', 'y']].shift(1).fillna(0)
df['new_col']= df['x']*df_shifted['x']+df['y']*df_shifted['y']
```

The output looks like this:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(dict(
        ID= [1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
        time= ['02:37', '05:28', '09:01', '10:05', '10:52'],
        x=[1, 3, 4, 7, 1],
        y=[2, 4, 3, 2, 6]
    )
)

df_shifted= df.shift(1).fillna(0)
df['new_col']= df['x']*df_shifted['x']+df['y']*df_shifted['y']
df

Out[474]: 
   ID   time  x  y  new_col
0   1  02:37  1  2      0.0
1   1  05:28  3  4     11.0
2   2  09:01  4  3     24.0
3   3  10:05  7  2     34.0
4   3  10:52  1  6     19.0
```

So it kind of mixes the rows of different IDs. So the Value of ID 2 is calculated with the last row of ID 1. If you don't want to have that, you need to work with `groupby` like this:

```
# make sure, the dataframe is sorted
df.sort_values(['ID', 'time'], inplace=True)

# define a function that gets the sub dataframes
# which belong to the same id
def calculate(sub_df):
    df_shifted= sub_df.shift(1).fillna(0)
    sub_df['new_col']= sub_df['x']*df_shifted['x']+sub_df['y']*df_shifted['y']
    return sub_df

df.groupby('ID').apply(calculate)
```

The output looks like this on the same data as above:

```
Out[472]: 
   ID   time  x  y  new_col
0   1  02:37  1  2      0.0
1   1  05:28  3  4     11.0
2   2  09:01  4  3      0.0
3   3  10:05  7  2      0.0
4   3  10:52  1  6     19.0
```

You see, that now the first entry of each group is 0.0. Mixing doesn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def myfunc(d):
    return d['x'].mul(d['x'].shift()) + d['y'].mul(d['y'].shift())

df['new_col'] = df.groupby('ID').apply(myfunc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming index is numeric,

```
(df.join(df.groupby('id')[['x','y']].shift(),lsuffix='1',rsuffix='2')
   .apply(lambda x:some_function(x.x1,x.x2,x.y1,x.y2),axis=1))
```